# Are there lots of points with this property?

Tags: calculus

Leithold in the section 2 of the first chapter of his Calculus book gives the point $P=(1,-2)$ and asks to find such point $T$:

[image]

The answer in the final of the book is $T=(-2,1)$. I found this point but a lot of the other points. Are there just this point or am I missing something?

Comment: There is only one point.

Comment: @b00nheT exactly, I think the same

Comment: The line between $P$ and $T$ is bisected by another line, hence other points on this line do not work.

Comment: You are most definitely right

Comment: @T.Bongers I'm sorry, could explain a little bit more?

Comment: Draw the picture of this setting. If a line bisects segment PT, does the same line bisect segment PR if R is a different point?

Comment: The point $T$ is the reflection of the point $P$ in the line $y = x$.  Given a point $(a, b)$ in the plane, its reflection in the line $y = x$ is the point $(b, a)$.  For a given point $P$, there is only one such reflection.